# Do we have to pray as soon as the time for prayer comes?

Tags: salat, prayer-timings

Do we have to pray as soon as it is a valid time to do so or we have the whole time between two prayers (lets say for example its time to pray Duhr but I prayed befor Asr starts in 30 mins).

Another case would be Its time to pray Fajr but i prayed once i have waked up is my salah not accepted as i should have woken up as soon as it was valid to pray Fajr?

I know that Fajr And Isha because of their timing they are considered as a challenge, so me waking up later than i should is making things in my own comfort, is this haram, brothers and sisters please advice!

Comment: Brother, times for prayers are indicated by god. I recommend you to read this carefully: http://www.quran-islam.org/main_topics/islam/pillars/number_of_salat_(P1200).html

Comment: Related: [Should salah be done as soon as possible?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/51467/)

Answer (score 1):

Allah has made prayers to be done at certain times =

**"...Indeed, prayer has been decreed upon the believers a decree of specified times."** [4:103]

Only exception the Prophet gave for making up missed prayers was if one forgets to pray or oversleeps =

**"Whoever forgets a prayer, let him offer it as soon as he remembers, for there is no expiation for it other than that."** [[al-Bukhari]](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:597) [[Muslim]](https://sunnah.com/muslim:684a) and other books.

**'There is no negligence when one sleeps, rather negligence is when one is awake. If any one of you forgets a prayer or sleeps and misses it, let him pray it when he remembers it.'** [[an-Nasai]](http://sunnah.com/urn/1106190)

Otherwise the prayer has to be done when the time comes in.  And when it comes in for prayers like Dhur, Asr, and Maghrib, the timing is up until the next payer enters.

Like Dhur prayer doesn't end until Asr prayer comes in.  Asr prayer doesn't end until Maghrib comes in.  And Maghrib doesn't end until Isha comes in.

But Isha ends when it's half the night and not up until Fajr time.  **You can read the full *hadith*** [here](http://sunnah.com/muslim/5/223)

Fajr ends when dawn has past and the sky is light.

Comment: Jazak allah kher brother, so i take it that i will be not committing a sin if i prayed an hour later than the adhan of asr for example (current country which i live in does not have adhan and limited on mosques in case of jamm'a

Comment: Yes bro as long as the time of maghrib hasn't entered.